# How To Make This design only with HTML AND CSS

Tags: html, css

I Try research about this design to make only with HTML and CSS 
but not able to do it. is anyone can help me with this, thank you

[View post on imgur.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6H1p.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```css
.quarter{
      border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
    border-top: 15px solid rgba(37, 187, 161, 0.5);
    border-bottom: transparent 15px solid;
    border-left: solid 15px transparent;
    border-right: solid 15px transparent;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translateY(-7px);
    z-index: 1;
}
.circle{
  border-top-left-radius: 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;
    border-top: 10px solid #10bd9f;
    border-bottom: 10px solid #475f79;
    border-left: solid 10px #10bd9f;
    border-right: solid 10px #475f79;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.mint{
  color: #10bd9f;
}
.navi{
  color: #475f79
}
p{
  margin: 0;
}
.text{
  text-align: center;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    position: relative;
    top: 15%;
    transform: rotateZ(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="quarter">

</div>
<div class="circle">
  <div class="text">
    <p class="mint">Debt <br>50%</p>
    <p class="navi">Equity <br>50%</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: PersyJack Thank you So much ☺